# DC/OS Vagrant VMs cannot access the GUI after vagrant halt and vagrant up

Tags: dcos

I have successfully installed dcos-vagrant with one master and one slave node using: `vagrant up m1 a1 boot`. However, after stoping the cluster with `vagrant halt m1 a1 boot` and restarting it with `vagrant up m1 a1 boot` I cannot access the GUI at `https://m1.dcos`.

How to stop the cluster without having to destroy it (`vagrant destroy -f`) and create it from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That functionality is not currently supported: https://dcosjira.atlassian.net/browse/VAGRANT-7